# Static Html player

Tags: angularjs, html

How to make static html player (mp3/mp4) using angular js.

when page navigate the. player should be static. it should not be load. how i can do it.

http://174.36.108.2/castbox_dev/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is encode your `mp3` or `mp4` files to `base64`. You can find plenty of information on Google on how to do that. Once you have `base64` files you just add them to your `HTML` like you would with a static image, so they won't be fetched from the server